# Finding a portion of the volume of a 3D object

Tags: calculus, volume

I was learning about volumes of revolution and I have a question. Here is a curve, $y=5^\left(x-2\right)-\frac{1}{25}$, which is bounded by, $y=5$ and $x=0$, [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q5prdiktkh).

Finding the volume of the shape as it's rotated about the y-axis. First, I solved for *x*, because I'm rotating about the y-axis. And thus, $\textrm{radius}=\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2$, we know that the area of a given cross-section at any height of the object *y* is, $\pi\left(\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right)^2$. The total volume of the solid is, $\int^5_0{\pi\left(\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right)^2}\delta y$, which yield's, $\approx95.976$. If this is the total volume of the solid, how could I find a specific portion of the volume? If I wanted to know at exactly what height half of the volume lies I could use, $\int^x_0{\pi\left(\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right)^2}\delta y=\frac{\textrm{Total Volume}}{a}$, where in this case *a* would equal 2, *(for half of the total volume)*, and *x* would equal the height at which the solid would need to be cut in-order for the volume from 0 to *x* would equal half of the total volume.

How could I solve for *x*? I'm sure there is a way to do it with the integral there, or I'm making an assumption that there must be a way to get that height after doing some operation with the original 2D curve.

I tried guessing and checking the height to, $\approx3.15193$, with that height for *x* the total volume is, $\approx47.98819$, so I assume there must be a way to calculate the value of *x* without guessing and checking or iteration (sums are fine).

An explanation including ***every*** step would be nice.

Comment: You’ll have to evaluate the integral, get an expression in terms of $x$ and then try to solve the resulting equation. Do you know how to integrate by parts?

Comment: @Tavish, could I ask how I would do this?

Comment: "$\int^5_0{\pi\left(\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right)^2}dy$, which yield's, $\approx95.976$."  As Tavish's comment suggests, it depends on how you arrived at this conclusion.  If you are able (somehow) to determine the antiderivative $F(y)$ of the function, then you could solve $F(x) = [F(5)/2].$  Assuming not, you have to take a microscopic view of your numerical approximation methods : ie $A(5) = \approx95.976$.  If you can arrive at a formula for $A(x),$ in terms of $x$ with satisfactory accuracy, then set $A(x) = [(A(5)/2].$  ...see my next comment

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you could do the integral, you’d get an equation containing $x$ and $\ln x$, which I don’t think can be solved by hand.

Comment: The only alternative that I am aware of would be to use computer assistance.  That is, you would (for example) compute $A(x)$ for $x \in \{0.1, 0.2, \cdots, 4.9, 5.0\}.$  Then, when you determined $x_1, x_2$ such that $A(x_1) < [A(5)/2] < A(x_2)$ then you would repeat for $x \in \{x_1, [x_1 + 0.1], \cdots, [x_1 + 0.9], x_2\}.$  Then, you could continue this process iteratively, until reaching the required number of decimal places accuracy, for your estimation of $x.$

Comment: @Jacob135Evans wow. That was definitely not my intention. I apologize if my comment offended you. Just trying to say it's pretty hard to read w/o paragraphs. Maybe languages like "have to" and "understand" are too strong.

Comment: @Tavish "you’d get an equation containing $x$ and $\ln(x)$, which I don’t think can be solved by hand." I strongly suspect that you are right.  That is, even if you converted $\ln(x)$ to a Taylor series, it still does not facilitate hand computation of $x$.

Comment: @user2661923 Iteration is what I want to avoid here, it is essentially the same as guessing and checking for a better and better approximation of the value. I would prefer an equation which needs better and better inputs *(with more decimal points)* to get better and better outputs. And your first comment helps, thank you!

Comment: "Iteration is what I want to avoid here" : Actually, this depends on what you mean by iteration.  You can **dynamically** write the comptuter program to automatically identify $x_1, x_2$ and then automatically perform the next step in the iteration, identifying (for example) $x_3, x_4$ where $x_3 + 0.01 = x_4.$  Then you can have the program automatically identify $x_5, x_6$, where $x_5 + 0.001 = x_6$.  You can also (for example) require that the computer calculate to exactly $6$ significant digits.  I suspect that this approach is in very widespread use among computer *solvers*.

Comment: @user2661923 Any equation, formula, or generalization is fine. It doesn't matter to me if I can solve it by hand or not.

Comment: Then, assuming that Tavish's comments are accurate, which I have not verified, I would consider converting $\ln(x)$ to a Taylor series.

Comment: You can ask this question with 20% of the words, and will get more help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V=\pi  \int_0^5 \left(\log _5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right){}^2 \, dy=^*\frac{2 \pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}\approx 95.9764$$
Therefore to know where is the $y^*$ which divides the solid in half I set (RHS is half $V$):
$$\pi  \int_0^t \left(\log _5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right){}^2 \, dy=\frac{\pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}$$
which gives the non-algebraic equation
$$\frac{\pi  \left(2 t+\frac{1}{25} (25 t+1) (\log (25 t+1)-2) \log (25 t+1)\right)}{\log ^2(5)}=\frac{\pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}$$
Setting $25t+1=z$ and simplifying
$$2 z+z \log ^2(z)-2 z \log (z)=127+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)$$
*Mathematica* gives
$$z\approx 79.7981551 \to t\approx 3.1519262$$

---

$^*$

$$ \int \left(\log _5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right){}^2 \, dy=\int \left(\frac{\log \left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)}{\log (5)}+2\right)^2 \, dy=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\log ^2(5)}\int \left(\log ^2\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+4 \log (5) \log \left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+4 \log ^2(5)\right)\,dy=$$
$$F(y)=\frac{1}{25 \log ^2(5)} \left(50 y+(25 y+1) \log ^2(25 y+1)-2 (25 y+1) \log (25 y+1)\right)+C$$
Then $V=F(5)-F(0)$

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I calculated the integral $\pi\int^5_0\left(\log_5\left(y+\frac{1}{25}\right)+2\right)^2\delta y$ to be $\approx95.976389534$, but you set it equal to $\frac{2 \pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}\approx71.1355090626$?

Comment: @Jacob135Evans No, no. $$\frac{2 \pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}\approx 95.9763895340149$$

Comment: Sorry I had used Symbolab as a quick way to check it, and it was interpreting the logs as base 10 not as natural logs. WolframAlpha cleared that up for me, my bad.

Comment: Also could you please explain how you got $\frac{2 \pi  \left(125+63 \log ^2(126)-126 \log (126)\right)}{25 \log ^2(5)}$, I now know that it **is** equal to the integral, but how did you get that?

Comment: @Jacob135Evans I added a note $^*$ to explain some details, then you should know integration by parts to arrive to the result

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and explanation!